# Вывести несколько слов с пробелами в файл

Tags: c, файловый-ввод-вывод

На ввод в консоль подается несколько слов через пробел. Нужно вывести эти слова в файл. И записать их в выходной файл.
У меня эта функция записывает в выходной файл только первое слово.
что я делаю не так?

```
void write_to_the_endfile(char* path_in) {
    FILE* in = NULL;
    char newstr[1000];

    printf("путь = %s\n", path_in);

    if ((in = fopen(path_in, "r+")) == NULL) {
        printf("файла не существет");
        printf(" puty nulevoy n/a\n");
        fclose(in);
    } else {
        fseek(in, 0L, SEEK_END);
        printf("Введите новую строку: ");

        fscanf(stdin, "%s", newstr);
        printf("новая строка: %s\n", newstr);
        fputs(newstr, in);
        /* вторая попытка реализации
        while (newstr[0] != '\n') {
            fscanf(stdin, "%s", newstr);
            printf("новая строка: %s\n", newstr);
            fputs(newstr, in);
        }*/
        fclose(in);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Это -

```
fscanf(stdin, "%s", newstr);
```

чтение одного *слова*. Для чтения строки следует использовать функцию

```
fgets(newstr,1000,stdin);
```

Comment: Супер! помогло!  Но он получается статичный всего лишь на 1000 занков. я вот видел такую конструкцию.  `char* newstr;
        size_t len = 0;
        getline(&newstr, &len, stdin);` В рамках моей функции такой или подобной конструкцией можно пользоваться?

Comment: Это нестандартное расширение. Зависит от того, какие условия наложены на программу, и какой компилятор используется.